# Input value from different form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two forms on my page...

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="form1_submit_pushed"/>
</form>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="form2_submit_pushed/>
</form>
```

On my php side I want to be able to know the value of the text input "name" when I push the submit button of the second form. Kind of like....

```
if(isset($_POST['form2_submit_pushed']))
{
    echo $_POST['name']; //or something else?
}
```

The reason behind is that first form has a bunch of data that I don't want in the second form submission.

Comment: no u cant get this way since since name is a part of first form. However u can wrap a JS to submit the 2nd form by getting the form1 input fields.

Comment: how do you do that? Does it involve maybe hijacking the click method, then using a "clone" object, inject it into form2 and then submit the 2nd form? If so, how do you submit a form from a javascript function?

Comment: document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); I am guessing

Comment: I don't think this can be done. At least not on the PHP side because the info you're looking for isn't posted. I'm the furthest thing from being a JS pro, but maybe you can do what you want through JS and a hidden input in your second form that is updated onChange of the name field.

Comment: one thing u can do set a hidden field called name in 2nd form and on submit the 2nd form set the value by getting it from first form. Give an id of name on first form as name1 and name2 on second form and then submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this...this code uses jQuery:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="form1_submit_pushed"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="form2_submit_pushed" id="form2_submit_pushed">
</form>

<form id="form2" method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="form2_submit_pushed"/>
</form>

<script>

$('#form2').submit(function(event) {
    //prevent form2 from submitting and submit form1 instead...

    event.preventDefault();

    //before submitting, indicate that the "form2_submit_pushed" button was pushed
    $('#form2_submit_pushed').val(true);
    //submit form1
    $('#form1').submit();
});

</script>
```

...but why you would want to I don't know. Why not make all the controls part of the same form? HTML is designed to send info from only one form (at a time) to the server...

**UPDATE**: Sorry, I didn't notice your line where you explain your reason for wanting to do this. If you want more explicit control over what gets sent to the server I recommend using AJAX to submit the form. Look at https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ and https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong here, but I beleive normal HTML will only post the inputs from the form you are posting from. One option would be to have a hidden input on the second form which gets updated via javascript during the input's change event.

So, you could do something like this (I don't recommend inline javascript but it should get you in the right direction):

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onchange="document.getElementById('hiddenname').value=this.value"/>
    <input type="submit" name="form1_submit_pushed"/>
</form>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" id="hiddenname"/>
    <input type="submit" name="form2_submit_pushed/>
</form>
```

Then you just need to get it using 
    $_POST['hiddenname'];

Comment: Please don't advocate inline JavaScript

Comment: I obviously didn't advocate it. I specifically said I don't recommend it in my answer.

Comment: Then your answer is just lazy, as you used inline JS.